Why is Group Delay Dispersion excluded from the Split Step Fourier Method?
I have been looking recently into the Split Step Fourier Method (SSFM) for propagating optical pulses in fibers. The SSFM is used to solve the Nonlinear Schrödinger Equation (NLSE) where various effects like dispersion and self-phase modulation (SPM) can be taken into account. For example, a commonly used equation is:
$$\begin{equation}\frac{\partial A(z,t)}{\partial z}=\frac{\beta_2}{2}\frac{\partial^2A(z,t)}{\partial t^2} -\frac{\alpha}{2}A(z,t)+i\gamma\mid{A(z,t)}\mid^2A(z,t)\end{equation}$$
Here, A(z,t) is the complex field envelope, $\beta_2$ is the Group Velocity Dispersion (GVD), $\alpha$ is the loss factor, $\gamma$ is the nonlinear coefficient describing SPM. You can choose to add higher-order dispersion terms like $\beta_3,\beta_4,...$, and so forth.
In almost all the sources I found, the first order dispersion term $\beta_1 \frac{\partial A(z,t)}{\partial t}$, also known as Group Delay Dispersion (GDD), is always omitted. What is the reason for that? It seems straightforward to implement in the computation. Can I benefit from including it?
My hunch is that SSFM uses the Slowly-Varying Envelope Approximation (SVEA), which assumes a constant group velocity $\nu_g$ for the envelope. If however, the optical pulse that we are trying to propagate is very broadband, then the group velocity becomes a function of the frequency $\omega$, meaning that $\nu_g$ is not constant anymore and that the pulse does not propagate as a compact packet from segment to segment but can rather spread over multiple segments.
